# Read json data from controller odoo 9

Tags: json, ajax, odoo, odoo-9

In controller I'm put 3 users:

```
@http.route('/test_json', type="json", auth="public")
    def some_json(self):
        return json.dumps({"id": 1,"name": "Leanne Graham"},{"id": 2,"name": "Leanne Graham 2"},{"id": 3,"name": "Leanne Graham 3"})
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/test_json", 
        async: false, 
        data: JSON.stringify({}), 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        complete: function (data) { 
              var mydata = JSON.stringify(data);
              alert(mydata)
              alert("How get only name in alert for user)
               },
        error: function () {
              alert("Error")
              }
         });
```

In alert get

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": null, \"result\": \"{\\\"id\\\": 1, \\\"name\\\": \\\"Leanne Graham\\\"}\"}","responseJSON":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"result":"{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Leanne Graham\"}"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

How get all user (3 users) and in ajax alert display name for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

why alert ,use log  and firebug

example

$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/test_json", 
        async: false, 
        data: JSON.stringify({}), 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        complete: function (data) {

```
           },
    error: function () {
           console.log("error");
          }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the `json.dumps` method [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps).

A dictionary as the `obj` argument of the method corresponds to a json object and you can only have one "root" object there while you have three. To achieve want you want try enclosing all your dictionaries with another dictionary:

```
@http.route('/test_json', type="json", auth="public")
    def some_json(self):
        return json.dumps({{"id": 1,"name": "Leanne Graham"},{"id": 2,"name": "Leanne Graham 2"},{"id": 3,"name": "Leanne Graham 3"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@http.route('/test_json', type="json", auth="public")
def some_json(self):
    return json.dumps({"ids":[{"id": 1,"name": "Leanne Graham"},{"id": 2,"name": "Leanne Graham 2"},{"id": 3,"name": "Leanne Graham 3"}]})

$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/test_json", 
        async: false, 
        data: JSON.stringify({}), 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        complete: function (data) { 
              var results = data[responseText"]["result"];
              var names = [];
              results.map(function(v){
                  names.push(v['name']);
              });
              alert(JSON.stringify(names));

        },
        error: function () {
              alert("Error")
              }
         });
```

Comment: Tnx for help, in console get error results is undefined  https://postimg.org/image/tpn0w37tx/